# Designing a cache-optimized N-ary tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, caching, tree

I'm looking for ways on how to best design a N-ary tree that will effectively use the cache. I expect the vast majority of operations on the tree will be node-to-root traversal so thats the usecase I want to target, meaing I'm fine with insertions/deletions being fairly expensive.

Ontop of my head, storing the nodes front-to-back (i.e root at the end) is one desired property. And then I guess you can store it either in BFS or DFS - which is best for this case? Does it matter, once the tree reaches a certain size?

I also briefly came across this http://www.cs.au.dk/~gerth/papers/soda02.pdf - it sounds promising but this is not a BST and I have no need for searching of any kind, just child-to-root traversal.

EDIT: Yeah will need to implement it ontop of vector/array, so contiguous memory. It does not need to be a BST. Nodes are accessed directly via random access property of vectors/arrays, it is the traversal to the root from there that is the issue

Any ideas?

Comment: _Why_ are you traversing the tree? To find the nodes between the leaves and root, I assume? How do you find the right leaf node in the first place?  If you find leafs via a `Node*`, then you can't move them, which complicates insertions.

Comment: Could you store your nodes in a contiguous data structure, such as a vector? How large is your data, and how large is your tree?

Comment: Not sure I totally understood the question, but If you want a BST that uses the cache go for a B+ tree. There's already a bunch of implementations lying around. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree

Comment: You'd sometimes get lucky with DFS-ordered storage, but it would, in general, be pretty bad, since only one child will be anywhere close to the parent in memory, where as with BFS you can consistently get 2 layers at a time. But if some children are accessed significantly more often (and you know this) or many nodes only have 1 child, DFS-ordered would be a lot better. Although it sounds like you're trying to solve a problem already largely solved by b-trees.

Comment: Maybe my answer to this recent question is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777859/cache-aware-tree-impementation/. It stores the tree in a contiguous area, and includes the parent id in the information of each node, so it would be easy to go towards the root.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at Judy Arrays:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judy_array